# PHP/MySQL: how to display the words before and after the searched item

Tags: php, html, mysql, sorting

In my database, I have these words:
AA, AB, AC, AD, AE, AF, AG

I search for “AD” as:

```
<form method="post" action="AF9.php">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search">
        <input type="text" name="search" />
</form>
```

I want to sort all the words in the database alphabetically. Then only display the searched value (i.e., AD) and the word before and the word after. Something like this:

- AC
- AD
- AE

Here is what I have written so far (your help is greatly appreciated):

```
<?php
include('includes/db_AF.php'); //includes the db credentials
$connection = @new mysqli(HOSTNAME, MYSQLUSER, MYSQLPASS, MYSQLDB);
if ($connection->connect_error) {
  die('Connect Error: ' . $connection->connect_error);
} else {

  $search=$_POST["search"];

  $query="SELECT word FROM wordtable2
  WHERE word like '%' 
  ORDER BY word ASC";   // I am sorting all the words in the database                       

  $result_obj = '';
  $result_obj = $connection->query($query);         

  while($result = $result_obj->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
    $items[] = $result;
  }                             

  foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item['word']; //Here I need to echo the results, but don't know how to
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: You would probably have to query for the next and previous words. `SELECT word FROM wordtable2 WHERE word < ? ORDER BY word DESC LIMIT 1` and `SELECT word FROM wordtable2 WHERE word > ? ORDER BY word ASC LIMIT 1`. Aside from that, you could also maybe work something out with getting a row number and querying for rownumber-1 limit 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way to do this in SQL, but the easiest way I can think of actually involves two queries.

using your example...

lets say your database has the following entries

```
AA, AB, AC, AD, AE, AF
```

Following your example, you have the value AD and you want to retreive AC and AE.

First, do a query like this...

```
SELECT word FROM wordtable2
    WHERE word > 'AD'
    ORDER BY word ASC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Then do a query like this...

```
SELECT word FROM wordtable2
    WHERE word < 'AD'
    ORDER BY word DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to say something like:

```
echo $items[$item];
```

If used in the context of your foreach() loop, this will display each word in your $items array.